# Linux Expect Script terminates too early

Tags: linux, expect

I have an expect script that I have written that at the end calls `scp` to copy a large file from server A to server B.

The issue I have (which is the same using `rsync` and not `scp`) is that the expect script is terminating before the file transfer is complete. I know that I can set the timeout in expect but as the file size grows so will the timeout.

Is there anyone that has come across this issue and is there a wait function that I can use in expect?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://oreilly.com/catalog/expect/chapter/ch03.html, you can simply set `timeout` to `-1` to disable the timeout mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Two things, number one, yes, `set timeout -1` if you do not want it to timeout.

Secondly, you should use `wait` to allow the `scp` or `rsync` command to complete. Simply waiting forever is not nearly as robust...

Last comment, I was an `scp` user for quite some time but have really grown to love the ***delta, partial*** and ***sparse*** abilites of `rsync`. With these, even if the transfer is disconnected, it can pick back up where it left off which is immensely helpful at times....especially if waiting forever anyway ;)

Something like:

```
rsync -a -v -i --timeout=30 --stats --log-file="$LOG_FILE" --partial --exclude 'log*.txt' "$DATA_DIR"/"$DATE" $DEST:"$DEST_DIR"
```

(This pushes from the node to the master)

Doing this can save some serious bandwidth when transferring large files, spotty networks, etc...